# Stipe checkout on multiple pages

Tags: javascript, angular, stripe-payments, checkout, credit-card

I am building a Stripe checkout flow, this is my first implementation of it and so I have a few questions that I did not found answers to:

(I am using Ngx Stripe for angular for now - but it seems I cannot create billing information pages)

1. Can you split the checkout flow on multiple pages? (Payment details in one page, address details on another) - any links would be appreciated
2. Ngx Stripe does not seem to have address elements so I think I need to revert to StripeJs.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Point 1 and 2 is the question, and it seems pretty clear to me :(

Comment: What do you mean by "checkout flow"?  Stripe Checkout is a Stripe hosted form to accept payments.  Checkout will handle collecting all the necessary billing information for you and ensure you can handle any applicable payment methods.

Are you using Checkout or Payment Elements?

Comment: I am using Stripe Elements.